# Window decoration of emacs23 window on fluxbox is outside screen

Tags: ssh, xorg, emacs, fluxbox

I am starting emacs remotely over an ssh connection.

But on the emacs window I cannot find a way to resize or move it. There is no fluxbox title bar visible, and I guess the title bar is above the visible viewport, because emacs starts vertically with more height than the screen has. The lower border of the emacs window is also below the viewport border, so I cannot resize the window.

I am starting emacs like this:

```
emacs23
```

This is the emacs version:

> This is GNU Emacs 23.1.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.20.0)
>   of 2010-03-29 on yellow, modified by Debian

The remote system that runs emacs is 10.04 Lucid Lynx amd64. The local system is running 9.10 Karmic Koala 32 bit and Fluxbox 1.1.1-2

Comment: so what is your question? how to start emacs so that you can see the decorations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround which I post as an answer, but I would prefer if someone comes up with a real solution:

When I start emacs like this

```
emacs23 -g 98x36
```

I get a viewport that exactly fits my screen and all of the fluxbox window decoration is accessible.

I found out the values 98 and 36 by trying different numbers.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround I can imagine is to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>, left-click on the window and drag it so that you can see the upper/lower border.

Comment: I tried, but alt left-click is not recognized. The mouse ist still active inside the window.

Answer (score 0):

You can start **emacs** in a terminal to start without a GUI.

**How do you do this?**

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and enter the following command:

```
emacs -nw
```

Might be convenient if you are using SSH.